# Call a function from a script and have it run in the original script

Tags: function, powershell

I have two seperate powershell scripts that need to be run at the same time. One is a kiosk, and the other is a script that detects idle time and calls a function in the kiosk script. The function is designed to close the kiosk and reopen it to clear any form data. The only issue is that it doesn't close the original kiosk instead opens a new instance.

I have attemped to combine the scripts into one but have had no luck in getting it to work.

Here is the idle time script:

```
Add-Type @'
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace PInvoke.Win32 {

public static class UserInput {

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=false)]
    private static extern bool GetLastInputInfo(ref LASTINPUTINFO plii);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct LASTINPUTINFO {
        public uint cbSize;
        public int dwTime;
    }

    public static DateTime LastInput {
        get {
            DateTime bootTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMilliseconds(-Environment.TickCount);
            DateTime lastInput = bootTime.AddMilliseconds(LastInputTicks);
            return lastInput;
        }
    }

    public static TimeSpan IdleTime {
        get {
            return DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(LastInput);
        }
    }

    public static int LastInputTicks {
        get {
            LASTINPUTINFO lii = new LASTINPUTINFO();
            lii.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(LASTINPUTINFO));
            GetLastInputInfo(ref lii);
            return lii.dwTime;
        }
    }
}
}
'@

    for ( $i = 1)
    {Write-Verbose ("Idle for " + [PInvoke.Win32.UserInput]::IdleTime)
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1

    if ([PInvoke.Win32.UserInput]::IdleTime -gt "00:00:10.0000000")
    {Stop-Process -processname kiosk*
    C:\kiosk.exe MakeNewForm
}
```

The idle time is set to 10 seconds for testing. It will be longer of course when in production.

And here is the kiosk script:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
$URL = "www.website.com"
$event = {$Browser.Print()}

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

#Browser Refresh
Function MakeNewForm {
    $mainForm.close()
    $mainForm.dispose() 
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100

    # WinForm
    $mainForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $mainForm.Text = " Internet Explorer"
    $mainform.WindowState = "maximized"
    $mainForm.ControlBox = $false
    $mainForm.FormBorderStyle = "none"
    $mainForm.MinimumSize =  "1024, 768"
    $mainForm.Top = $true


    # Back
    $back = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $back.Size = "55, 55"
    $back.Location = "875, 0"
    $back.BackgroundImage = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile('C:\back_button.jpg')
    $back.Add_Click({$Browser.GoBack()})

    $mainForm.Controls.Add($back)

    # Forward
    $forward = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $forward.Size = "55, 55"
    $forward.location = "953, 0"
    $forward.BackgroundImage = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile('C:\forward_button.jpg')
    $forward.Add_Click({$browser.GoForward()})

    $mainForm.Controls.Add($forward)

    # Go Home
    $gohome = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $gohome.Size = "55, 55"
    $gohome.location = "75, 0"
    $gohome.BackgroundImage = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile('C:\home_button.jpg')
    $gohome.Add_Click({$browser.URL= "$URL"})

    $mainForm.Controls.Add($gohome)

    # Print
    $button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button 
    $button.Size = "54, 55"
    $button.Location = "0, 0"
    $button.BackgroundImage = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile('C:\print.jpg')
    $button.Add_Click($event)

    $mainForm.Controls.Add($button)


    # Browser
    $Browser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser
    $Browser.IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled = $false
    $Browser.URL = $URL
    $Browser.Location = "0, 0"
    $Browser.Dock = "fill"


    $mainForm.Controls.Add($Browser)
    }



# WinForm
$mainForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$mainForm.Text = " Internet Explorer"
$mainform.WindowState = "maximized"
$mainForm.ControlBox = $false
$mainForm.FormBorderStyle = "none"
$mainForm.MinimumSize =  "1024, 768"
$mainForm.Top = $true


# Back
$back = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$back.Size = "55, 55"
$back.Location = "875, 0"
$back.BackgroundImage = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile('C:\back_button.jpg')
$back.Add_Click({$Browser.GoBack()})

$mainForm.Controls.Add($back)

# Forward
$forward = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$forward.Size = "55, 55"
$forward.location = "953, 0"
$forward.BackgroundImage = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile('C:\forward_button.jpg')
$forward.Add_Click({$browser.GoForward()})

$mainForm.Controls.Add($forward)

# Go Home
$gohome = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$gohome.Size = "55, 55"
$gohome.location = "75, 0"
$gohome.BackgroundImage = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile('C:\home_button.jpg')
$gohome.Add_Click({$browser.URL= "$URL"})

$mainForm.Controls.Add($gohome)

# Print
$button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button 
$button.Size = "54, 55"
$button.Location = "0, 0"
$button.BackgroundImage = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile('C:\print.jpg')
$button.Add_Click($event)

$mainForm.Controls.Add($button)


# Browser
$Browser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser
$Browser.IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled = $false
$Browser.URL = $URL
$Browser.Location = "0, 0"
$Browser.Dock = "fill"


$mainForm.Controls.Add($Browser)

$mainForm.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

I have tried . .\idle.ps1, do{}while(), combining the the idle script to the end of the kiosk script but nothing has worked when combining them.

Is there is a way to either combine these or have the idle actually call the function and have it run in the kiosk script?

Thanks in advance for any replies or advice!

Comment: To get an idea of the business logic here would you like to monitor the idle time and when it hits 10 seconds, to execute the code in the kiosk script?

Comment: The kiosk script is to be running the entire time, along with the idle time script. After the alloted time is reached the script is to call and execute the "MakeNewForm" function inside the kiosk script. What is happening is that the kiosk is not closing, but the idle script is just opening a new instance of the kiosk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I completely forgot to mention that these would be compliled to run as an .exe. What I eneded up going with is with the **stop-process -processname kiosk*** and it is working flawlessly now. Thank you again MFT for pointing me in the correct direction. I will update the above script to show the changes.

```
if ([PInvoke.Win32.UserInput]::IdleTime -gt "00:00:10.0000000")
{Stop-Process -processname kiosk*
C:\kiosk.exe MakeNewForm
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method is sound. What you need is to write the process id of the kiosk script into something persistent, i.e a text file. This can then be used for the idle script to reference from and kill the original process if needed.The current process id of a Powershell session can be acessed via the built-in variable $pid.

To save the process id of the current session

```
$pid | Out-File -FilePath c:\kiosk-pid.txt
```

To access it later and use it to kill the process

```
Get-Process -PID ([int32](Get-Content -Path C:\kiosk-pid.txt)) | Stop-Process
```

Comment: That works amazingly well.  The only issue is that the new form that is created will no always have the same process ID. I never thought about the Stop-Process cmd. With that said, I completely forgot to mention that these would be compliled to run as an .exe. What I eneded up going with is with the stop-process -processname kiosk* and it is working flawlessly now. Thank you again MFT for pointing me in the correct direction. I will update the above script to show the changes.

Comment: Glad that it helped. Out of curiosity, what are you using to compile it to Powershell?